# Remove CSS hover functionality using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I need to remove CSS hover functionality using JavaScript.

I have a button on a form which submits data to our db server. Using `OnClientClick()` of an ASP.NET Button control I would like to change the element's text to 'Submitting..' using `getElementById()`, change the background color of the button to Light Grey and **more importantly disable the following .button:hover effect** I have in my CSS.

```
.button:hover, 
.content-form input.button:hover, 
#comment-form #submit:hover   
{
    background-color: #333;
}
```

All I am really interested in is the Javascript to remove/disable the above CSS

```
e.g. OnClientClick="getElementByID('ButtonName').blahblahblah;"
```

Comment: Per my understanding, you want to remove hover style but not class itself. right?

Answer (score 4):

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bm576q6j/17/

```
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var n = elms.length;
function changeColor(color) {
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        elms[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    elms[i].onmouseover = function() {
        changeColor("gray");
    };
}
```

Edit: Sorry for not noticing last part of your question before I answered :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your css is wrong.  It should be:

```
.button:hover, .content-form input.button:hover, #comment-form, #submit:hover    {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

and you are adding css with id and class. You should not do that. Just add with class  and use `document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute('class')`

Comment: Thanks. Using my CSS quote button:hover etc.. would you be able to elaborate on what should replace "class" in your example above?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it removes the class attribute eliminating all defined classes, but then adds that should not be removed.

> On [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/89ham5gw/)

```js
function disableHover(elem) {
 elem.removeAttribute('class');
 elem.setAttribute('class', 'another');
}
```

```css
.button:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}

.another {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="disableHover(this);">hover</button>
```

But the **best way** of doing this is so, simple and works well.

```js
function disableHover(elem) {
    elem.classList.remove('button');
    elem.classList.add('another');
}
```

```css
.button:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
.another {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="disableHover(this);">hover</button>
```

> On [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/89ham5gw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of solutions for solving your problem.

For example:

1- Using `HTML disabled attribute`.

```
OnClientClick="getElementByID('ButtonName').disabled=true;
```

2- Add a class which overrides  the previous style.

```
.button:hover, 
.content-form input.button:hover, 
 #comment-form #submit:hover    
 {
    background-color: #333;
 }

 .button.submitted:hover
 {
    background-color: gray;
 }
```

Js:

```
OnClientClick="getElementByID('ButtonName').className = "submitted";
```

and etc